# Shuls that say Hungarian Selichos?

Tags: minhag, synagogue, nuschaot, nusach-ashkenaz, selichot

Are there any shuls (I'm preferably looking for shuls in Yerushalayim) that say the Hungarian(/Bohemian/Moravian/Silesian) selichos for the Yemei HaSelichos?

(This is the selichos that is found in the Rosenfeld Slichos, the Machzor Polin, and [this](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=51237&st=&pgnum=1&hilite=)).

Comment: Around Yeshivas Pressburg? Kiryas Mattersdorf?